# Get module name as parameter in request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the best way to get my module name as a function paramteter (entity) in request function?.
I tried the following but is not working at all (Page not found). Something is wrong in the url regex? :

```
url(r'^<entity>=accounts/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z\-]+)/activate_entity/$', activate_entity)

def activate_entity(request, entity, pk):

entity_model = apps.get_model(app_label='entities', model_name=entity)
entity_object = entity_model.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is wrong. try the following

```
url(r'^(?P<entity>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z\-]+)/activate_entity/$', activate_entity)
```

and the url will be,
**`/{entity_name}/{pk}/activate_entity/`**